# error al instalar react-export-excel - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Instale `npm i react-export-excel` en mi proyecto de reactjs pero me carga un error y no he podido solucionar:

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\proyecto\node_modules\react-export-excel\node_modules\xlsx'"

No me deja utilizar esta librería en mi proyecto, y así cree otro proyecto y vuelva a montar la librería siempre aparece el mismo error.**

Answer (score 0):

tuve que ir a la ruta `"node_module/react-export-excel/node_modules/xlsx/package.json"` y agregar al final del archivo

```
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false
      }
```